# using if else with a dataTable in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, if-statement, datatable

Let me start off by stating that I am very new to C#.  I am using a DataTable to display data from an SQL database.  I am trying to use if else to dynamically display a row in a table if the data in the database cell has data but if it is null, that section of the table does not display.

Why is it always printing the else section of code and not if even when a cell is null?

Here is a section of my code:

C#

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    PullDataConn.Open();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    PullDataConn.Close();

    int rowCount = dt.Rows.Count;

    string html = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        html += "<div class='divContainer'>" + 
                    "<table class='resultsTable1'>" + 
                    "<tr><td colspan='2' class='tdCoName'>";
        html += dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(0);
        html += "</td></tr>" + 
                    "<tr><td class='contactCat'>HotLine</td>" +
                    "<td class='tdHeadingPadding'>";
        html += dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(1);
        html += "</td></tr>" +
                    "<tr><td class='contactCat'>e-Mail</td>" +
                    "<td class='tdHeadingPadding'>";
        html += dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(2);
        html += "</td></tr>";

        if (dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(3) == null)
        {
            html += "<tr><td colspan='2' style='height:10px;'></td></tr></table></div>";
        }
        else
        {
            html += "<tr><td class='contactCat'>Other</td><td class='tdHeadingPadding'>";
            html += dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(3);
            html += "</td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' style='height:10px;'></td></tr></table></div>";
        }

    }

    ResultsDiv.InnerHtml += html;
```

Comment: Can you debug this and determine exactly what `dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(3)` contains? I suspect that what you think is `null` is really some other empty value: `&nbsp;`, `''` or something similar.

Comment: @ethon10 The value is nothing at all.  How can I do an IF ELSE with a completely blank field? For testing can't i just type NULL in the cell of the table?   If so, when I do this, the value for 3 is {}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `GetValue(3)` is typically a `string`, you could try this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString())) {
   // hide it
} else {
   // show it
}
```

As you mentioned, you are new to C#, but consider posting another question regarding a better way to build up your html. I'm not attacking you or your chosen early attempts at this, but the good folks of StackOverflow could absolutely help you make that portion better (performance, readability, etc.).

Comment: @OP the `StringBuilder` class might be of interest.

Comment: My thoughts exactly, but I didn't want to sound too critical. I want to help OP without scaring away.